# How does the for loop work in a Bash script?

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
USER=root
KEY=~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
for HOST in server1 server2
do
    ssh -l $USER -i $KEY $HOST grep -I "Invalid user" /var/log/secure | awk '{ print $10 }'
done
```

I understand the `grep` line returns the IP addresses of "invalid user" attempts, but can anyone clarify the `for HOST ..` line? I'm not understanding what exactly this script does.
Also when I put `server1=workshop2` (my hostname) I receive the error `ssh: cannot resolve hostname workshop2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a for loop that sets HOST to the server names in sequence. These need to be names that you could ssh into, so `workshop2` isn't working. Try to find an address for that server that you can reach via ssh on the command line. You can also just list the servers after `for HOST in`. Replace server1 and server2 with the actual names.

For each server in the list, the script logs into the server and runs the grep command looking for "Invalid user" in `/var/log/secure`. For each line it finds, it uses awk to print out the 10th item in the line.

Answer (score 1):

The idea seems to be to find out which IP address are trying to wiggle their way into your servers, as you already figured out.

`for` is a shell iteration construct, running the iteration for each server in a list of names. "server1 server2" is that list in your example.

The reason you are having trouble is that you are using *your* hostname for `server`. `ssh` already knows that bit of info, thank you. What ssh wants is the hostname of the *target* machines that this script is trying to monitor. `ssh` will create a remote session with the server, run the grep... command sequence, spit out the IP addresses, and close that session - that is one for iteration here.

The error message comes because you don't have a way to run a remote shell session into your own machine. You are already there!

Take a look at `man ssh` for tons of more details. I would have also suggested `man bash` but you will find much easier-to-consume manuals online.

HTH.